# When I append to an HTML table using jquery I can't trigger the table row click event

Tags: c#, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc

I'm using asp.net mvc. I'm trying to append to an HTML table using jquery. I get the rows from a getJSON call and append them to the table. The rows are appended but for some reason the added rows don't trigger the click event. I think maybe it has to due with the timing or something but I'm not sure.

controller

```
using System;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace Test
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult Test(string x)
        {
            string strJson = "[{\"name\":\"tom\",\"number\":\"111\"},{\"name\":\"bill\",\"number\":\"222\"}]";
            return Json(strJson, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }

    }
}
```

view

```
@{
    Layout = null;
}

<style>
    td {
        border: 2px solid black;
    }
</style>

<br />
<br />

<table id="table1">
    <tr>
        <td>
            name
        </td>
        <td>
            number
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>

<br />
<br />

<button id="button1" type="button">append rows</button>

<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-3.4.1.js"></script>

<script>

    //table click event
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $("#table1 tr").click(function () {

            alert("table row clicked");

        });

    });

    //button click event
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $("#button1").click(function () {

            $.getJSON('@Url.Action("Test")', { x: "1" }, function (y) {

                y = $.parseJSON(y);

                $.each(y, function (i, item) {

                    $('#table1').append('<tr><td>' + item.name + '</td><td>' + item.number + '</td></tr>');

                });

            });

        });

    });

</script>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The event isn't triggered because the row is added after the event handler is attached. Use:

```
$(document).on("click", "#table1 tr", function (){}
```